# Finding the index of a set of characters in huge sequence of characters

Tags: java, hashmap, sequence

Let's say I have an extremely large sequence of characters of A-D, 4 Billion to be exact. My goal is to find the indexes of several new sequences of letters that are set at length 30 within that large sequence of characters. The problem also increases in difficulty when the sequence you are looking for has a small error (a letter is wrong).  How should I tackle this problem?

The trivial method is to iterate one letter at a time across the whole 4 Billion text file, but that'll take forever with memory running out.

I've been told to utilize a hashmap, but I'm not sure exactly what to use as my key value pair. The idea of using regex has also come up, but I'm not entirely sure if it'll work with my problem. Any help in terms of direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's an illustration of what I'm asking: [image]

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic problem call the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (LCS).  There are many algorithms to solve it.  The genome project does this kind of search a lot.  The wiki link provided has many examples.  Your threshold for errors would be a special case.

Are you doing something with gene sequencing?  I ask only because you mention only 4 variables :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the author's problem does not involve the length of the substring at all. In his case this is not a _longest_ common subsequence problem- simply find all of the indexes of a given substring. Or would a longest common subsequence algorithm solve his problem regardless?

Comment: @AlexLynch Good question.  The LCS is the general problem.  There are multiple solutions to it.  Some return the length of the LCS, others return the actual sequence. Still others return all indices.  The basic logic is the same though.  What the OP would wind up doing is something like this:  `LCS(<desired_sequence>, <long_sequence>);`

Comment: @linuxuser27 I'm having a hard time understanding the algorithm and I'm a little confused as to where I should start. I think it does the job in term of finding the sequences, but how will it declare the index in a huge data set? Do I feed it chunks of the whole reference sequence or am I supposed to hash the sequences one by one?

Comment: @bigbitecode The Hirschberg algorithm for this will give you that information.  As far as understanding the algorithm, that is typical.  The LCS problem has many solutions and the more efficient you get the more complex.  The classic CLRS algorithm book has some great details on how it works.  I would start there if you have the text.  If you don't, I would follow the pseudo code, implement it, and run it on some small strings while stepping through the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

By encoding in characters you are wasting 14 bits on every 2 you use. You could encode four nucleotide letters in just a single byte, then you'd need only half a gigabyte. As for an algorithm, you can study the code in `java.lang.String.indexOf` and the Wikipedia page on [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

BTW you could make the search instantaneous if you employed the Lucene index for this. The idea would be to index every 30-letter subsequence as a separate document in Lucene. As for error tolerance, you'd need to use N-grams, or make a fuzzy search (in Lucene 4 there's a new algorithm to quickly locate strings with edit distance up to 2 or 3).

Comment: Marko, that method looks a lot more efficient. How would I encode the characters into four nucleotide letters? The thought of having this all done instantly sounds a little too good to be true, but I have heard great things about Lucene. How difficult is it to setup a Lucene index to search for such queries?

Comment: As for encoding, you take for example an `int[]` and make each `int` in it represent 32/2 = 16 nucleotides. You treat the `int` as a bitfield. It's hairy programming, but if you choose carefully what kind of operations to implement, the hairy bit could be isolated in a few functions, the rest of code seeing just an array of nucleotide letters.

Comment: @bigbitecode As for Lucene... well, you'd need to spend a day or two getting to know the API. You'll need a `KeywordAnalyzer` instead of the default `StandardAnalyzer` for indexing and searching (this will become meaningful once you go through the basic tutorial). The reason why it really can be almost instantaneous is because you're creating an inverted index, so searching by your 30-letter sequence is just like a `HashMap.get` operation.

Comment: @bigbitecode Now that I think of it, the best approach would be to index with an Analyzer that would automatically create 30-letter subsequences out of your main sequence. That could involve some custom programming, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and easy bit of code to deal with the representation.

```
public static enum Nucleotide { 
    A,B,C,D;
}

public static int setbit(int val, int pos, boolean on) {
    if (on) {
                    // set bit
        return val | (1 << (8-pos-1));
    }
    else {
                    // unset bit
        return val & ~(1 << (8-pos-1));         
    }
}

public static int set2bits(int val, int pos, int bits) {
            // set/unset the first bit 
    val = setbit(val, pos, (bits & 2) > 0);
            // set/unset the second bit
    val = setbit(val, pos+1, (bits & 1) > 0);

    return val;
}

public static int setNucleotide(int sequence, int pos, Nucleotide tide) {
            // set both bits based on the ordinal position in the enum
    return set2bits(sequence, pos*2, tide.ordinal());
}

public static void setNucleotide(int [] sequence, int pos, Nucleotide tide) {
            // figure out which element in the array to work with
    int intpos = pos/4;
            // figure out which of the 4 bit pairs to work with.
    int bitpos = pos%4;
    sequence[intpos] = setNucleotide(sequence[intpos], bitpos, tide);       
}

public static Nucleotide getNucleotide(int [] sequence, int pos) {
    int intpos = pos/4;
    int bitpos = pos%4;
    int val = sequence[intpos];
            // get the bits for the requested on, and shift them
            // down into the least significant bits so we can
            // convert batch to the enum.
    int shift = (8-(bitpos+1)*2);       
    int tide = (val & (3 << shift)) >> shift;
    return Nucleotide.values()[tide];

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int sequence[] = new int[4];
    setNucleotide(sequence, 4, Nucleotide.C);
    System.out.println(getNucleotide(sequence, 4));
}
```

Obviously there's a lot of bitshifting going on, but the small # of comments should make sense as to what's going on.

Of course the downside of this representation is that you are working in groups of 4.  If you want say 10 nucleotides, you'll have to keep another variable somewhere with the count so that you know the last 2 nucleotides in the sequence aren't useful.

The fuzzy matching can be done with brute force if nothing else.  You would take a sequence of N nucleotides in, then, starting at 0, check against nucleotides 0:N-1 and see how many match.  Then you go from 1:N then 2:N+1, etc...